# Javascript Swap Three Paragraphs

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hi my swap function is not working as properly intended what am I missing I can't seem to find the problem see below. Thank you in advance!

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Three Pharagraphs</title>
 <script>
    function swap(a,b) {
        var c = a.innerHTML;
        a.innerHTML = b.innerHTML;
        b.innerHTML = c;
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        var link1 = document.getElementById('link1.1');
        var link2 = document.getElementById('link2.2');
        var link3 = document.getElementById('link3.3');
        var p1 = document.getElementById('line1');
        var p2 = document.getElementById('line2');
        var p3 = document.getElementById('line3');
        link1.onclick = swap(p1,p3);
        link2.onclick = swap(p2,p3);
        link3.onclick = swap(p1,p3);
    }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <p id="line1">What is Lorem Ipsum?</p>
    <p id="line2">Why do we use it?</p>
    <p id="line3">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage.</p>
    <p><a href="#" id="link1.1">1<->2</a> <a href="#" id="link2.2">2<->3</a><a href="#" id="link3.3">3<->1</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the link1,2 and 3 onclick functions like that:

```
        link1.onclick = function() {
          swap(p1,p3);
        }
        link2.onclick = function() {
          swap(p2,p3);
        }
        link3.onclick = function() {
          swap(p1,p3);
        }
```

Comment: This solved my problem thank you! Is that the normal way to call a function in Javascript?

Comment: You set what will be the function when you click the button.
In your example you call the function and save the result to onclick, but its undefined since swap function returns nothing

Comment: Okay got it thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function and setting what it returns to the onclick. What you are doing is basically `link1.onclick = undefined;` since the method does not return anything.

```
link1.onclick = function() { swap(p1,p3); }
```

Comment: Okay that is why it doesn't function well, thank you for that information!